# CrudRepository in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

How can I get all objects from the database

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView recoverPass(@RequestParam("num") int num) {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("test");
    mv.addObject("lists",appRepo.findAll(num));
    return mv;
}
```

I typed http://localhost:8080/test?num=40 in the browser but no result.
The error is : findall in CrudRepository cannot be applied to (int)

Answer (score 1):

The CrudRepository in Spring does not have a method called findAll() which takes an integer argument. findAll() with no arguments returns all the objects not just a given one for a specific integer id.

You need to work out what you want. If you want all the objects then call findAll() with no arguments and get rid of the int parameter.

If you only want to find a specific object with the given integer id then use findOne(num) instead.

Comment: Thank you i want to find all objects with a specific field value

Comment: @RayEn, then you should use something like `match` query

Comment: @RayEn If you want to do that then you'll need to use Spring data query methods. Say your field is called foo with a String value then add a method to your appRepo interface called findByFoo(String foo) and Spring data will magically make it work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to solve paging. In this case use PagingAndSortingRepository or JpaRepository over simple CrudRepository as in that case there is a `findAll(Pageable pageable)` method available which does exactly what you want.

Reading: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts

Answer (score 0):

The [CrudRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) in Spring has only `findAll()` method witch returns all items from table. 
If you want to get all items you should use

```
appRepo.findAll();
```

or you should declare method with needed condition:

```
@Repository
public interface AppRepo extends CrudRepository<Foo, Long> {
    List<Foo> findBySomeValue(String someValue);
}
```

and use it in your logic `appRepo.findBySomeValue('bar');`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get user with id=40. If you are using spring data jpa with spring boot, you can create a repository say `userRepository` and create a method findById() to get user of specific id.

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Serializable>{
    User findById(Long id);
}
```

You can then autowire `UserRepository` in your service and call findById() method. Also you can use same `UserRepository` object to get all user list by calling findAll() method.